# play2 mini Action not found

Tags: playframework-2.0

Steps to reproduce the problem:
1:in window environment is running ok,EG:192.168.0.207:9091/insert?id=1 SUCCESS
2:open DOS WINDOWS,under the project path: sbt->dist generation the directory
rserver/bin;rserver/config;rserver/lib;rserver/deploy
3:put the all directory in linux environment 
4:i write a xshell(run.sh) to run the project(it contains akka.kernel.Main class)
5:./run.sh start ,console message is 
Starting Akka... 
Running Akka 2.0.3 
Deploying file:/opt/playmini/deploy/cti-kernel-1.0.0.jar 
=========start====record=============  (see here)
Starting up CtiKernel 
Play server process ID is 8084 
[info] play - Application started (Prod) 
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9091 
Successfully started Akka

object RecordApp extends Application {

```
System.setProperty("http.port","9091")
System.setProperty("pidfile.path","/opt/pid")
val system = ActorSystem("RecordSystem")
val log = Logging.getLogger(RecordApp.system,this)
println("=========start====record=============")

def route = {
    case GET(Path("/insert")) & QueryString(qs) => Action{ request =>
      //val tenantId = QueryString(qs,"id").getOrElse(0)
      println("context:" + request.contentType)
      Ok("Pong1 @ %s\n".format(System.currentTimeMillis))
    }
  ...
```

6:but 192.168.0.207:9091/insert?id=1  respose Action not found  For request 'GET /insert?id=1'

please tell me why